# How To Remove Random People in CSGO Friends List?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Apparently CS:GO has this smart feature that's implemented in the most annoying and inconvenient way. If you are on the same network as other people and you both play CS:GO, the other person shows up in the friends list UI inside CS:GO. This is regardless of whether or not you are friends or if you have blocked all communications with them on Steam.

Is there any possible way to disable this feature, like through console, launch options or something like that? Please help, cause its really annoying to have all these random people pop up.

By the way, it still shows even if you are set as offline and also still if you use VPN.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by same network?

Comment: I mean they are logged on to the same network. The same wifi signal. Damn dem grammar corrections xD

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to remove them unfortunately. My best advice is to change your network settings to private. Hopefully someone on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/4wv7nq/how_to_remove_random_people_in_csgo_friends_list/) can give a briefer description.
This feature is mainly used to find and host LAN parties. It just makes the whole process easier.